# Magento2 graphql query to create product?

Tags: magento2, api, catalog, graphql

How to Create Product using graphql is there any mutation for this I couldn't find a single tutorial nor mutation in core **module-catalog-graph-ql**.

Comment: Magento does not provide a default product creation mutation. You should create a custom mutation for it.